# why need to use GraphQL relations when using Prisma?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server, prisma

I took a GraphQL course, and the instructor was using Javascript Objects (that act like tables) as a temp database, and so he was creating resolvers that handle relations between these objects, now, if I use a real db with Prisma,knowing that prisma already has handles those relations. should I still create those resolvers in GraphQL, also, Please point me to some resources that integrate both prisma and GraphQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the examples from the official repository. [This](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/javascript/graphql-sdl-first) example integrates Prisma with GraphQL using Apollo Server.

You need to write the resolvers in which you would use Prisma's API to fetch data from the tables.